# Receive SMS in Android 2.3 vs Android 4.0

Tags: android

I have written an SMS app to receive SMSes using the various samples available online. I tested it in a Android 2.3 device and it was working perfectly.

Now, I changed the API level to Android 4.0 and tried running it on an Android 4.0 device and nothing happens. I checked the logcat in Eclipse and nothing is displayed there too.

Any idea what needs to be done for it to work?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 1):

> Check Once Again that you are actually **creating and registering the
> broadcast receiver in an Activity** otherwise it will not get called
> as **after Android 3.1 it requires apps to be in started state to
> receive broadcasts**.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure, what u meant. How do i implement to ensure, "apps to be in started state to receive broadcasts"? For example, a SMS application will only becomes active after receiving the SMS and not before that.